# PHP Ratchet - send message from client to server on disconnect

Tags: php, websocket, chat, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I have a chat application, client code written in javascript and some jquery and server code is written with php

i'm using ratchet websockets : http://socketo.me/

according to the official tutorial : http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world , with javascript there are only two events : onopen and onmessage

i was wondering if i can detect the disconnection on the client side and send a message(example : JSON message) from the client **(with javascript)** to the server just before the client disconnects

i can detect that the client disconnected in the server but i can't get that message that i need

any ideas ?

Comment: How would you send it if you're disconnected?

Comment: i want the client to send a json message to the server just before he disconnects